# Reading csv file, remove stop words, find unique words

Tags: python, csv, stop-words

I am trying to read a csv file - it has 3 million tweets in it. Eventually, I want to remove the stop words, and get the top 2,000 unique words along with their frequencies. However, I am running into an error well before I get to that point. Here is my code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import csv

f = open("/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop/ShanTweets.csv")
shannon_sample_tweets = f.read()
f.close()

filtered_tweets = [w for w in shannon_sample_tweets if not w in stopwords.words('english')]
```

And the error I get after I run that is:

```
__main__:1: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going wrong? I did put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-,` in the top of my source code

Comment: Python gets mad when you try to compare unicode and non-unicode strings. It will be helpful to test the type of both your csv words and the stoplist words. To do so, try `for x in shannon_sample_tweets: print type(x)` and try `for y in stopwords.words('english'): print type(y)` Running these lines should tell you whether either or both are in unicode. Once you know which is not in unicode, you can bring that string into unicode with `unicode(string_thats_not_in_unicode)`. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you @duhaime -- the code you wrote tells me that shannon_sample_tweets is `<type 'str'>` and stopwords is `<type 'unicode'>`, but when I ran the command `unicode(shannon_sample_tweets)` I get the following error

`>>> unicode(shannon_sample_tweets)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd5 in position 100: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good, your comment clears things up. To get your csv into unicode, you should run: `import codecs` then:

`f = codecs.open("/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop/ShanTweets.csv","r","utf-8")`

Then if you recheck the type of your csv, you should see unicode. This is of course assuming your Tweets are utf-8 compliant, which appeared to be the case (I took a quick peek!). If you plan on working with strings in Python, I recommend reading up on encodings--they will become important for your work.

Comment: Thank you -- I actually modified this to change to -Latin1 (instead of utf-8) to finally get it to work.